# How to have html code in the middle of the page

Tags: html, center

I want to learn html code for a school project, I don't know how to have letters* in the middle (horizontally) of the page to make it more presentable. I'm new to coding so please try to make it simple. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean text with "code"? So that you'll get text in the middle of your screen?

Comment: yeah, i just want to input some words so they appear in the middle of the screen.

Comment: sorry I wrote it wrong the first time

Comment: @Bob, Do you want to make vertically and horizontally centered? then see my answer.

Comment: Thi may help you: http://howtocenterincss.com/

Answer (score 0):

To get text in the center of your screen (only using HTML), you can just make a paragraph with "text-align:center;". Your HTML code would be:

```
<p style="text-align:center;">Your text on the center of your screen</p>
```

An example can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/wbf600pk/
Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: yeah that is what im looking for

Comment: Have fun coding. If you're helped out please accepted the answer. :) You should also consider using CSS. This makes your code much better and readable when you're going to build a website in the future. Just Google for "CSS" for more information.

Comment: Ahh i see, ill be sure to try.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example how to center text vertically and horizontally;

```css
html, body, .container {
    height: 100%;
}
.container {
    display: -webkit-flexbox;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> <p>Text in the center</p>

</div>
```

Comment: This is better, but he only asked for HTML. Beside that, you would change the `span` of your code to `<p>`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but that seems a little too advanced for me right now.

Comment: No worries, save it for future.